# How can I improve my question?

Tags: discussion

[Origin of different network timeouts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375612/origin-of-different-network-timeouts)

I would like to know why e.g. linux uses 20 second timeout for socket connect. I can't find any information myself so I'm curious if anyone knows better sources or happens to know the rational off-hand. Are questions about historical purpose of a given unix/linux facet generally too broad? Or is there a way I can improve my question?

Comment: Well done on using Meta to get help improving your question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your questions were put *On Hold* as **too broad**

From [help-center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

> **too broad** - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or
>   has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are
>   correct), then it is probably too broad for our format
>
> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple
>   distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help
>   clarifying this question.

I think that having one specific question would be a good start.

**I'd rephrase it as follows:**

> Linux uses 20 seconds as default network timeout
>
> - What is the reason for this specific timeout value?
>
> **Note that:** java and bsd use different values for the network timeout 
>   (30 for java and ~75 for bsd)

If you have any references for the timeout values you mentioned, I'd add those references as a note.

Comment: You do have a point, and i applaud you for taking a crack at identifying just what's wrong with the question in question